# Show that $ab + bc +ac = 2abc +1 $ for given planes

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

> If the three planes with the equation below have a line in common, show that $ab + bc +ac = 2abc +1 $

$$\pi_1 : x+by+cz = 0 \\
\pi_2: ax+y+cz = 0 \\
\pi_3: ax +by +z = 0$$

I am not sure how to solve this problem. I am not sure if this is solvable using matrix.

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & b & c\\a & 1 & c \\ a & b & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1):

If the planes have a common line, then the system has infinite number of solutions, and consequently is the determinant of the matrix  zero. Just compute the determinant.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Call your matrix $M$ and set $\,v=(x,y,z)^T$, then we are looking for a nonzero $v$ (representing the direction vector of the common line) such that $Mv=0$, in other words the assumption is that the *kernel* of $M$ is not trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Subtract the second equations from the first one; the third one from the second one and the first one from the third. Then you get three new equations which gives as a result: $(1-a)x=(1-b)y=(1-c)z$. Plug everything in terms of x in the first (second and third will also do) equation. The you get $x(1+\frac{1-a}{1-b}b+\frac{1-a}{1-c}c)=0$. For $x\neq 0$ we can devide this equation by zero. We obtain after working a bit out: $\frac{(1-b)(1-c)+(1-a)((1-c)b+(1-b)c)}{(1-b)(1-c)}=0$. Since this fraction is equal to zero, we can ignore the denominator. Just write out all the brackets in the numerator and you will find your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Since line is a one-dimensional subspace, therefore the kernel of the matrix must be a one-dimensional subspace i.e. the rank of the matrix must be 2 (the determinant must be zero) and no row be a multiple of any other row: $$\begin{vmatrix}1 & b & c\\a & 1 & c \\ a & b & 1\end{vmatrix}=(1-bc)-b(a-ac)+c(ab-a)=2abc+1-ab-ac-bc=0$$which results what we sought. Also the condition that **no two rows are multiples of each other** holds automatically.